# How to multiply replace on the same column SQL

Tags: mysql, select, replace, workbench

I'm trying to replace all fields "name" by "name+1" in one update. For example, i want that 2008 become 2009, 2009 become 2010, etc.

I did this for just one replace :

```
UPDATE table
SET name = REPLACE(name, '2008', '2009');
```

But if i want to replace now 2009 by 2010, it will be wrong because it will change also 2009 of my last request.

Here is my db :

[image]

How can i increment all of these years "name" in one request without conflict and without start by the latest year ?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: You have name stored as a string?

Comment: Yes, the column type "name" is string.

Comment: start the opposite way. Increment first the highest and then move back. 2019 will become 2020, then 2018 will become 2019 and so on without overlapping

Comment: @LelioFaieta Oh yes it might be a solution by i want to increment them

Comment: you say you want to increment each year by one, so your last example doesn't apply. If you want to add one year you start from the highest, if you want to reduce by one you start with the lowest

Comment: Yes @LelioFaieta i understand now, that's a solution yes. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [`casting`](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-cast/) ( *as unsigned for numeric type* )

```
update table
   set name = cast(name as unsigned) + 1;
```

*considering your column(`name`) contains integer year values only.*

Comment: Thanks, that what i was looking for. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2):

As long as the column value is **purely numeric**, even if its data type is `varchar`, you don't need any casting. 
**MySql** does [implicit casting](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/type-conversion.html):

```
update tablename
set name = name + 1;
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eDJTurYxzzNZszxJjraSCR/4).